# jQuery not changing text on selection of option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok before I start I will let you know that I am using https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown in my page, but I have tried with and without the implementation of that source, so I don't think that has much to do with it.

Here is my select menu

```
<select id="payments2" name="payments2" style="width:100%; ">
    <option value="" data-description="Exchange To">Processor</option>
        <?php
            $processor = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `processors`");
            while($pro = $processor->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $pro['id']; ?>" data-image="<?php echo $pro['icon']; ?>"><?php echo $pro['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <form class="form-style-7">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="test">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="p1" name="test" maxlength="100">
                <span>Stuff Here</span>
            </li>
```

It populates fine, that is not the issue, here is the jQuery I am using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#payments").msDropdown({visibleRows:4});
    $("#payments2").msDropdown({visibleRows:4});
    $("#payments2 option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == $("#p1").text();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#payments2").live("change", function() {
        $("#p1").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

I am not sure as to why when I change my selection it does not show anything in the input box.

I am still kind of new to jQuery so it could be something simple, but I could use a point in the right direction.

Comment: `live()` was deprecated and removed from jQuery a long time ago. You should update your jQuery version and use the delegate of `on()`

Comment: in which browser are you testing?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please post that as an answer so I can check it as the correct fix because that was the issue, thank you so much

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, changing `live()` to `on()` fixed my problem, so your comment was the answer it is just I can not check it as such.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood :) I added it as an answer for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live()` was deprecated and removed from jQuery a long time ago. You should update your jQuery version and use the delegate of `on()`:

```
$(document).on('change', "#payments2", function() {
    $("#p1").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most likely in the use of the live function. This is no longer supported in jquery (it is deprecated). You can update your code to use delegated events like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#payments2", function() {
    $("#p1").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using .on(), not .live() anymore... it has been deprecated for a while now.